# Error Submitting iOS App with macOS Sierra GM (16A322) and xCode 8.0 for Review

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode8, macos-sierra

I am on macOS Sierra GM (16A322) using xCode 8.0 (8A218a) to compile an app that I would like to Submit to the App Store. I have read other threads on here indicating that this is not possible with beta versions of macOS or xCode, however Apple published a post on September 7th, 2016 that seemed to indicate this was possible with GM candidates.

[This post](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09072016a) included the following statement:

> "Build your apps using Xcode 8 GM seed, test with the GM seeds of
>   macOS Sierra, iOS 10, watchOS 3, tvOS 10, and submit them for review."

The app uploads to iTunes Connect from xCode without issue. 
Upon clicking to 'Submit for Review' the following message (which I have seen on other threads under different circumstances) renders:

> "New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions
>   of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with
>   beta software including beta macOS builds."

Wondering if anyone else has experienced this, or was able to find a cause or a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Sierra GM (16A322) has not been green lit by iTunes Connect yet. 
You should be able to build if you change the BuildMachineOSBuild to 15G31 in the Info.plist files in your archive before you Upload to App Store.

You can update all the files in one fell swoop by issuing this command in the directory containing your .xcarchive.

```
find ./*/Products/* -name Info.plist -print0 | xargs -0n1 plutil -replace BuildMachineOSBuild -string 15G31
```

Comment: Additionally Apple just released a [new GM seed to developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/). Have not tried submitting using this (16A323) but I'd bet it works.

Comment: I had this problem when submitting apps using High Sierra Beta (17A306f) in 2017.  hpeikemo's solution works just fine by using build number 16F73

find ./*/Products/* -name Info.plist -print0 | xargs -0n1 plutil -replace BuildMachineOSBuild -string 16F73

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am getting the same error. I am currently downloading El Capitan 10.11.6  on another computer (MacBook pro) and then will install Xcode 8 Release version again and attempt to submit my app for review again this way.

I'll hopefully keep you posted and let you know if this works.

This is what I was running on my iMac for the failed attempts!... 
macOS 10.12 (16A322)
Version 8.0 (8A218a)